# Setting android alarm manager on certain days

Tags: android

I'm building an app that uses alarm manager. The user sets day and time and there is 7 checkboxs, one for each day of the week and the ones they tick the alarm will go off on them days. Like i know you can put date and time into the alarm manager is there any way i can put like day and time into alarm manager and them it will go off on that day every week?

Answer (score 6):

[AlarmManager.setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) takes as parameter:

> **type**  One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP}, RTC or RTC_WAKEUP.

Here you will want RTC or RTC_WAKEUP

> **triggerAtTime** Time the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

Here you give the date/time of the first alarm (I believe this must be UTC time, so be careful)

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2011, Calendar.APRIL, 19, 23, 12);
long firstTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

> **interval**  Interval between subsequent repeats of the alarm.

To repeat every week, you will give as interval the number of milliseconds in a whole week:

```
long interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
```

or

```
long interval = 7 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
```

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted (using the check mark on the left) if this answer was useful to you and solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. I'm doing this myself and it's reassuring that the solution I'd arrived at is the one you offer here.