# Run code every day when app isn't open

Tags: android

I want to run some code every day (every 24 hours). Problem is if user doesn't open app. How to run code when the application isn't open?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333680/android-schedule-action

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting android alarm manager on certain days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715940/setting-android-alarm-manager-on-certain-days)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In android to run background periodic task you can use various ways and some of them are:

1. **JobScheduler (Only for API 21 or above)**

Android has added this class on API 21 for documentation here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html).

2. **JobSchedulerCompat - Backport of JobScheduler library for API 11 or above**

You can find everything about library [here](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat).

3. **Use alarm manager to handle periodic task**

You can also use `AlarmManager` to schedule periodic task. A full article to implement it is posted [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/).

4. **Use GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) Network Manager to schedule periodic task.**

You can have a look at this docs [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) to implement it.

**Example for periodic Task using GCM Network Manager**

Add dependency in your project level build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
```

Create a java class that extends to`GcmTaskService`

```
public class BackgroundTaskHandler extends GcmTaskService {

    public BackgroundTaskHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
         //Your periodic code here
    }
}
```

Declare the service in manifest.xml

```
    <service
        android:name=".BackgroundTaskHandler"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Now schedule the periodic task from any class as:-

```
    String tag = "periodic";

    GcmNetworkManager mScheduler = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    long periodSecs = 60L;// 1 minute

    PeriodicTask periodic = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setService(BackgroundTaskHandler.class)
            .setPeriod(periodSecs)
            .setTag(tag)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true).setRequiredNetwork(com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .build();
    mScheduler.schedule(periodic);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning there is now WorkManager which, when stable, is the recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The brand new way to implement scheduled operations is to use [job scheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), which is available from sdk level 21.

A simpler (and backported) way to perform periodic tasks has been (not so) recently added to google play services : [network manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager). Despite of its name, it is useful to schedule non network related tasks.

Check the

> Schedule a periodic task regardless of network and device charging states

section.

Comment: I don't think JobScheduler works on api 11 or above. As per documentation it was added on API 21.